# How to retain the values from dropdown category lists after wrong form submission?

Tags: categories, forms, dropdown, validation

I can't figure out the the code for - How to retain the values from dropdown category lists after wrong form submission? Any suggesstions, thanx in advance.

```
<select class="selectpicker btn-block" name="coupon_cat" id="category" >                                                    
        <option selected value=""> Категори Сонгох</option>
        <?php                                                       
             $args['exclude'] = "12,20"; // omit these two categories
             $categories = get_categories($args);
             foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id;?>"><?php echo $category->name;?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Ash was saying, something like this using $_REQUEST or $_POST will do it.

```
<?php
  $args['exclude'] = "12,20"; // omit these two categories
  $categories = get_categories($args);
?>
<select class="selectpicker btn-block" name="coupon_cat" id="category">
  <option value="">Категори Сонгох</option> <!-- if nothing else is selected, this will be selected automatically -->
  <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <?php $selected = (isset($_REQUEST['coupon_cat']) && $_REQUEST['coupon_cat'] == $category->term_id)?'selected="selected"':''; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id;?>" <?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanx @paul, it just works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check with $_REQUEST['coupon_cat'], Which gives value of selected category then compare it with your loop value so, you can make it selected.

$_REQUEST['coupon_cat'] will help you.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion, plz bear with me, can you plz tell me where I put this code in the above code.

Comment: thanx @ash, it just works fine!!